# What's meaning of range start=range end in http response

Tags: android, http, download

When I try to analyse CDN download, some logs looks like below:

```
 GET http://1234.apk?track=mmmmmmm range:bytes-sent=[500-500], content-length:1500 ...
```

In my understanding, range:bytes-sent represents continue download after break and it should have different number in bytes-sent, the followings are reasonable:

```
bytes-sent=[500-600]
bytes-sent=[500-]
bytes-sent=[-500]
```

but what meaning of range start = range end like *[500-500]*? It seems no data should be downloaded but generates http response.

Thanks first~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bytes mentioned in the range are also sent. Hence if the server wants to only send the 500th byte, the server would send  [500-500] as the bytes range. Have a look at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p5-range-26 which has an example of how the first and last byte are sent :

o  The first and last bytes only (bytes 0 and 9999):

```
    bytes=0-0,-1
```